# Fast implementation of convolution for CNN inference

Tags: conv-neural-network, gpgpu

I am looking for an advice for as fast as possible implementation of a convolution algorithm for CNN inference but not a training.

This convolution neural networks modeled as alexnet, mobilenet, resnet etc.. will run on embedded ARM device (A72, A53, A35) and possibly on embedded GPU as well.

I understand there is various implementation outthere and NN frameworks which have various implementations such as direct convolution, unrolling based convolution (im2col), FFT based or Winograd but mine primary focus is to execute CNN under performance constrain of embedded device.

If anybody has experience and can recommend convolution implementation for CPU and parallel implementation as well, point to research paper or open source implementation I would very appreciate it.

Comment: FFT has a time-based version such that it computes full ffp first, then only partial fft on each time step, I don't remember how it was called but maybe it fits your work?

Answer (score 0):

If it is still actual. I found a [small framework](https://github.com/ermig1979/Synet) to inference of pre-trained neural network on CPU. It uses [Simd Library](https://github.com/ermig1979/Simd) to accelerate its work.  The library has very fast (single thread) implementation of Convolution, Pooling, Relu and many other network layers for CPU (x86 and ARM). CNN convolution includes Winograd's method.